# Не могу понять,почему выдает ошибку?

Tags: c++

Добрый день.
Решаю задачи на с++, но не могу дорешать из-за некоторых ошибок:"multiple definition of 'main' "
Помогите справиться с этим,пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;

bool IsDigit(unsigned char c) {
if(isdigit(c))
     return true;
else return false;
}


int main(){
char c;
if (IsDigit(c))
    cout << "yes";
else cout << "no";
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Где-то в проекте есть ещё один файл с функцией main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, у меня компилируется.

Но работать оно не будет - вы же не задаете символ `c` и не считываете его с клавиатуры... Так что будет проверено - а не цифра ли какое-то мусорное значение?

А вообще все телодвижения с `IsDigit` вообще непонятны - какой в них смысл?...

Что по переопределения `main` - вы случайно не в какой-то уже имеющийся проект свою программу добавили? И где-то есть еще компилируемый и компонуемый файл с `main`?

Comment: Мне нужно написать функцию  определяющую, является ли данный символ цифрой или нет.Думал,что так и решается,через IsDigit.И,да,про ввод совсем забыл, парясь с этой ошибкой.

Comment: Просто чем ваше `if (IsDigit(c))` отличается от `if (isdigit(c))`? Ведь если записать вашу функцию чуть короче, то она выглядит так: `bool IsDigit(unsigned char c) { return isdigit(c); }` - т.е просто передает аргумент и возвращает возвращенное значение...

Comment: Просто в условии задачи было, что нужно реализовать решение через функцию, поэтому я написал такой бред.Спасибо за помощь,ваше решение намного рациональнее.